# How can I get crawlspider to fetch these links?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to fetch the links from the scorecard column on this page...

https://stats.espncricinfo.com/uae/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=1965;type=ground

I am using a crawlspider, and trying to access the links with this xpath expression....

```
"//tbody//tr[@class='data1']//td[last()]//a[@class='data-link']"
```

This expression works inside the scrapy shell, and fetches all 48 links. When I use the spider it scrapes nothing.

I have tried 20 different xpath expressions to no avail. I have also tried using 'allow' and css selectors as well. I believe I shouldn't include @href as the crawlspider takes care of this.

I am flummoxed as I have a very similar crawlspider that works with no issues.

Here is the full code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class IntlistmakerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'intlistmaker'
    allowed_domains = ['www.espncricinfo.com']
    start_urls = 'https://stats.espncricinfo.com/uae/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=1965;type=ground'
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//tbody//tr[@class='data1']//td[last()]//a[@class='data-link']"), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
       
        raw_url = response.url
  
        
        yield {
            'url': raw_url,
        }
```

The output

```
2021-05-25 18:03:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-05-25 18:03:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-05-25 18:03:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stats.espncricinfo.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stats.espncricinfo.com/uae/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=1965;type=ground> (referer: None)
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'stats.espncricinfo.com': <GET https://stats.espncricinfo.com/uae/engine/match/439500.html>
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 524,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18522,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.528078,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 17, 3, 8, 872122),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 48,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 17, 3, 7, 344044)}
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is the spider that works:

```
class ListmakerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'listmaker'
    allowed_domains = ['www.espncricinfo.com']
    start_urls = [psl21]
    

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@data-hover='Scorecard']"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
```

This spider successfully extracts the scorecard links from this page....

https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/ipl-2021-1249214/match-results

Please can anyone suggest how I can alter the xpath expression in the first example, so I can isolate and retrieve the scorecard urls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key line in the log is this one

```
2021-05-25 18:03:08 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'stats.espncricinfo.com': <GET https://stats.espncricinfo.com/uae/engine/match/439500.html>
```

You have set `allowed_domains` to `"www.espncricinfo.com"` which doesn't match with `"stats.espncricinfo.com"`. Change `allowed_domains` to `"espncricinfo.com"` to solve that.

In the version of `scrapy` I'm using `start_urls` has to be a list so you should fix that too.

Your `xpath` should now work. Try to keep them as simple as possible in the future. In this case a working `css` selector could be `".data1 > td:last-of-type > a"`

Comment: That has worked. Re start_urls, yes I am using a list, I just copied it across badly. I will try and brush up on css as this is indeed a much neater solution. Thanks a lot for your time.